# Import Activity with dup records

Tags: marketing-cloud, import

When trying to import a file with dup records by email address but different unsubscribe dates, is there a way to tell the system to load the record with the latest unsubscribe date?

Answer (score -1):

i would suggest you to process this data outside of SFDC and then import it.

To Process it outside you can sort you data by email and then by unsubscribe date.

This sorted data will help you to find out first email with latest unsubscribe date and ignore all other rows where email is same.

Once your data is cleaned up then simply import it.

Comment: This is ExactTarget tagged. Different importing processes.